# KeyCloak users rest api return 403 forbidden, why?

Tags: api, rest, keycloak

I got token using `http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/realm_name/protocol/openid-connect/token` endpoint.
After I need to get users of realm. Then I send request to `http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/experimental/users` endpoint without token. But I got 403 forbidden response with `"error": "unknown_error"` body. Why? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I solve it, all I need to add view users client role to my authenticated user